# RegEx for adding a comma and space in between first/last names

Tags: regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy, knime

I have a list of names where the last and first names appear together:

```
BorisovaSvetlana A.; KimHak Joong; PuXiaotao; LiuHung-wen*
```

I would like to add a comma and space between last and first names, for the output to be:

```
Borisova, Svetlana A.; Kim, Hak Joong; Pu, Xiaotao; Liu, Hung-wen*
```

I am using a String Manipulation node in KNIME and I think `regexReplace($col1$, ,"")` would be used and perhaps some kind of lookahead using [a-z] and [A-Z] to look for instances of a lowercase directly letter followed a capital letter, but I am new to regex so that's all I have so far.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/LSQsvQ/1) might help you to design a proper expression to match all your inputs:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z-]{1,})([A-Z]{1}[a-z-]{1,})
```

- It has two capturing groups one for first and the other for last names.
- It does not match Latin chars, if you wish so, you might change `a-z` to `\w`.
- You can simply create a string replace to replace `$1$2` with `$1, $2`.
- You can also add additional boundaries to the expression, if necessary.

---

It means that,

- One capital letter followed by one or more lowercase letters and dashes for the first names, and the same for last names, and you can simply change these boundaries inside the two groups as you wish.

[image]

---

#### Edit:

Based on [Pushpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102956/pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi)'s advice, it can be much simplified to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/HlEOqX/1):

```
([A-Z][a-z-]+)([A-Z][a-z-]+)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Emma! I think this solution would work perfectly. However, maybe running into issues using it in KNIME specifically, as it doesn't appear to be capturing any groups and simply returns nothing in place of the groups that should have been captured, i.e. ",  A.; ,  Joong; , ; , *" Will try to troubleshoot this further, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax in KNIME in String Manipulation node should be following:

```
regexReplace($col1$,"([A-Z][a-z-]+)([A-Z][a-z-]+)" ,"$1, $2")
```

Worked for me with your example. Regex can be similar as it worked with all 3 received/suggested in replays.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work! Is it possible to get this to work with names containing special characters as well? Like in this example, some names are not separated due to containing special characters: SánchezCésar†; Zhu, Lili‡; BrañaAlfredo F.†; Salas, Aaroa P.†; RohrJürgen‡§; MéndezCarmen†; Salas, José A.†§ I tried `regexReplace($col1$,"([A-Z][\\w-]+)([A-Z][\\w-]+)" ,"$1, $2")` but this did not change anything.

Comment: Not a regex expert but seems Ashok solution - `([a-z])([A-Z])` separates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression that you need is

```
([a-z])([A-Z])
```

1st Capturing Group ([a-z])
Match a single character present in the list below [a-z]
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)

2nd Capturing Group ([A-Z])
Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)